# Invalid search results while looking for contacts with non-latin characters

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contacts

I'm quite new on Android and recently I've faced such issue:

Im using Android Contacts database, specifically Data table. I'm putting there some info with new mimetype and trying to look for this info during search. The problem is, i'm using SQLite LIKE operator which is Case Sensitive for non-latin characters. Another problem is that i can't change databse in any way, because it's android built-in database.

```
Builder builder = Data.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();

loader.setSelection(getIndividualsSelection());
query = query.trim();
if( (null != query) && !query.equals("")){

    loader.setSelection(Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + 
        MY_MIMETYPE + "' " +   " AND  ( " + 
        MY_DATA_COLUMN + 
        " LIKE '"+ query + "%' " +
        specialCharsEscape + "  COLLATE NOCASE)");
    loader.setSelectionArgs(null);        
    loader.setUri(builder.build()); 
    loader.setProjection(MY_PROJECTION);
    loader.setSortOrder(MY_SORT_ORDER);

}
```

This is all inside of onCreateLoader funcion of LoaderCallbacks, where loader is of CursorLoader type. Do You have any idea how to force my SQLite not to be Case Sensitive?

I've tried off course using SQLite functions UCASE and LCASE but it doesn't work. Using Regexp results in exception for this database as well as using MATCH... Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Android has [localized collations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

To actually be able to use a collation for comparisons, use `BETWEEN` instead of `LIKE`; for example:

```sql
MyDataColumn BETWEEN 'mąka' COLLATE UNICODE AND 'mąka' COLLATE UNICODE
```

is the last UTF-8-encodable Unicode character; a Java string probably would encode it with surrogates as `"\uDBFF\uDFFF"`.

Please note that the `UNICODE` collation is broken in some Android versions.

Comment: How can I use BETWEEN to compare two strings? For example i want my code to find contact with mąka in data1 when i type mĄka.

Comment: Solution doesn't work. Instead of returning matching non-case sensitive records, it returns nothing.